# what is a proper way to register eventHandler

Tags: c#, .net

I was showing some of my code to a junior programer, and he asked me why am I registering functions for event handling like this:

```
button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click);
```

and not like this:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

The only thing I could say was: because you just write `+=` and press tab two times...

What is the difference between those two metods (if there is a difference)?

Comment: I would normally migrate this to Stack Overflow, however I know for a fact that it would simply be a duplicate there. However, I think it's OK for here too.

Comment: thx. I assumed answer will be that its thing of taste. so i posted it here.

Comment: In VS2012, it automatically creates the second one now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on what version of C# you are using.

The early versions required the `new RoutedEventHandler` while the newer versions don't.

They compile to the same code.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, if what you're doing in the handler is really short and not shared with any other events, I like this form:

```
button1.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    DoSomethingAwesome(e.RoutedEvent);
    e.Handled = true;
};
```